# Scroll does not work after an ajax call in Chrome & Safari but works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been searching for this solution but nothing worked for me.

I am simply sending an ajax request and loading back an HTML table with data from the database. The problem is, in chrome I cannot scroll down to see some table element. but I can scroll in Firefox. Cannot scroll in Safari too.

Here is my jQuery ajax call.

```
<script>
    function find(){
        var data = $("#id").val();
        if (data == "") {
            alert("Please Write Student user name or ID");
            return false;
        }
        $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
            $(".loading").css("display", "block");
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $(".loading").css("display", "none");
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/ajax-video.php',
            data: { 
                id: data
            },
            success: function(data) {                       
                $(".res").html(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                // failed request; give feedback to user
                alert("Something Went Wrong");
                $(".loading").css("display","none");
            }    
        });
    }
</script>
```

Could you please help me.
Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, no one will be able to know the problem here based only on that code. Can you replicate the problem using a fiddle please?

Comment: Thanks, not being able to create it in fiddle.  But it works if I give a fixed height of the res class. overflow:auto;height:900px. But don't work if I try to set the height dynamically after calculating the height of the table.